# Raspberry Pi does not register Servo on the I2C bus when connected via SparkFun auto pHat board

Tags: i2c, servo

I just want to move the Servo motor through the I2C pins on spark fun's auto pHat board. I've been using the pi_servo_hat import and have been setting the motor through the initializer like this:

```
test = pi_servo_hat.PiServoHat()
test.begin()
test.move_servo_position(0,90)
```

but I've been getting this error:

```
OSError: {Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

I pinged the I2C bus through i2cdetect -y 1 and got no output on the default port 0x40 and could not find any port become active after connecting the servo. I'll attach a photo of my setup.

[image]

was wondering how to get the I2c bus to recognize the servo motor.

Comment: This sounds like a question for the vendor.  Remote I/O error normally indicates a wiring problem on the I2C bus.  Check the connections.

Comment: @joan any idea if I'd be missing a step for initializing the servo motor? Is it as simple as plugging in the servo motor and rebooting the raspberry pi, once the board has been plugged in?

Comment: Ah, "***OSError: {Errno 121] Remote I/O error***" is the most I2C newbie FAQ. The frequent causes include: (1) wires loosen, (2) wires too long, (3) too many I2C devices overloading the bus (Note 1), (4) too many I2C module built in I2C pullup resistors exceeding standard I2C spec's 400 pF limit, (5) Bus frequency too high causing signal destortiom. ***Troubleshooting suggestions*** (a) Remove all module built in 4k7/10k pullup resistors (Rpi I2C on board cct has strong 1k8 pull up,, (b), (c), ...

Comment: References: ***Raspberry Pi 4 I2C bus not working correctly*** - Asked 1 year, 9 months ago, Viewed 10k times
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757687/raspberry-pi-4-i2c-bus-not-working-correctly/62786449#62786449